# Trying to send data with axios got the error 404 not found laravel/vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to save data from Vue.js to a Laravel controller with axios, but I am getting this 404 not fund error when I try with postman and on console.

After I triend to change the axios path to:

```
axios.post('storeInvoice' , {item: this.selectedItem , invoice_id:this.invoice_id}).then(response=>{
                    console.log(response);
                })
```

I got 405 Method not allowed
web.php

```
Route::post('storeInvoice', [InvoiceController::class , 'storeInvoice']);
```

Items.vue

```
  axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/storeInvoice' , {item: this.selectedItem , 
              invoice_id:this.invoice_id}).then(response=>{
                    console.log(response);
                })
```

InvoiceController.php

```
    public function storeInvoice(Request $request){

      dd('added'); //just for testing purpose
    }
```

full web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController;
use App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ItemController;
use App\Http\Controllers\InvoiceController;
use App\Http\Controllers\CompanyDetailsController;


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index')->name('home')->middleware('auth');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    Route::resource('categories', CategoryController::class);
    Route::resource('customers', CustomerController::class);
    Route::resource('items', ItemController::class);
    Route::resource('invoices', InvoiceController::class);

    Route::get('invoice/export', [InvoiceController::class , 'export'])->name('exportInvoice');
    Route::get('item/export', [ItemController::class ,'export'])->name('exportItem');
    Route::get('customers/export', [CustomerController::class ,'export'])->name('exportCustomer');

    Route::post('storeInvoice', [App\Http\Controllers\InvoiceController::class , 'storeInvoice']);
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::resource('user', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController', ['except' => ['show']]);
    Route::get('profile', ['as' => 'profile.edit', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@edit']);
    Route::put('profile', ['as' => 'profile.update', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@update']);
    Route::put('profile/password', ['as' => 'profile.password', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@password']);
});
```

Comment: try  ```'storeInvoice'``` rather than entering the whole URL ```'http://127.0.0.1:8000/storeInvoice'```.

Comment: Now I am getting 405 (Method Not Allowed) error

Comment: ok. make a closure function rather than make call to a controller function see if it even hitting the route or not.

Comment: Also, try one more method enter the full controller path in the , ```Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');```. See if this works or not

Comment: Does this route lie under `web.php` or the `api.php`?

Comment: @Alea.can you show full web.php code

Comment: I edited my question and added full web.php code